# Passing $id from href to controller for deleting the row laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to pass an id to a function in my controller to delete the row but I get the error code:

> Too few arguments to function 0 passed and exactly 1 needed

Here is my html code:

```
<a href="{{ route('undo', $id) }}">Undo</a>
```

this is my route:

```
Route::get('/admin', [ProductController::class, 'deleteProduct']) -> name('undo');
```

and this is my controller code:

```
function deleteProduct($id) {

        DB::table('products') -> where('id', '=', $id) -> delete();

        return view('auth.admin');
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, I'm trying to pass it trough a link, not a form... Maybe I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I would guess that the line `Route::get('/admin', [ProductController::class, 'deleteProduct']) -> name('undo');` should be `Route::get('/admin/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'deleteProduct']) -> name('undo');` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not define the `id` in your route:

```php
Route::get('/admin/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'deleteProduct']) -> name('undo');
```

This way the `route` call will know where to put the `id` and sent it to the function.

Another way is to leave the route as you have it, but remove the `$id` from your controller function definition, and add `Request $request` to make laravel object the request object. Than inside the function access the `$id` from the request object:

```php
$id = $request->input('id');
```